# enabling button upon textbox length condition c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to Enable BtnSubmit based on the length of TxtPswrd being greater than 8. I am using the Textfield Validating function, I am confused, should I used Validating, Validated or TextChanged functions?

```
 private void BtnSignin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // SqlConnection con = StartCon();
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
                if (textBox.Text != string.Empty)
                {
                    DataInserted(sender, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fill All Fields", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    TxtID.Focus();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

the DataInserted function:

```
private void DataInserted(object sener, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = StartCon();
            string AdminLookup = "Select count(*) from signin WHERE memid = '" + TxtID.Text + "' and adminpass='"+TxtPswrd.Text+"'";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(AdminLookup, sqlConnection);
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", TxtUsername.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", TxtPswrd.Text);
            
            if (command.ExecuteScalar().ToString() =="1")
            {
                SetValueForText1 =  TxtUsername.Text;
                new Thread(() => new PSP_Manager().ShowDialog()).Start();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error Signing in", "Check Credentials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlexception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", sqlexception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            StartCon().Close();
        }
    }
```

I am trying to enable the BtnSubmit **only** when the TxtPswrd.length >= 8

help, please.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqybs.png)

Comment: where is BtnSubmit in pic ?

Comment: @AmitVerma my mistake, it is the Singin button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a TextChanged:

```
private void PasswordTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  submitButton.Enabled = passwordTextbox.Text.Length >= 8;
}
```

because I'd want the submit button to enable while they were still focused in the box, as soon as they'd typed 8 chars

In other news, don't write SQL commands like that; see http://Bobby-tables.com for why..

..and also don't store passwords in plaintext in a database; doing so is the reason http://haveibeenpwned.com has to exist

Comment: Thanks for answering but it did not work, I tried tweaking the code a bit but no response. I called the method on the `Form_Load` Event and the button remained disabled.

Comment: I can't really do anything with an error report of "*it did not work*" - be more specific please. You wouldn't put this code as a Form_Load event handler, because that only happens once for the entire life of the form

Comment: @CaiusJard answer is correct."PasswordTextbox_TextChanged" this is text change event and it will fire automatically, you don't have to call this from form_load().

Comment: @UnknownReality to attach a TextChanged handler to a textbox, double click on it on the form designer and the code view will appear with a TextChanged handler created, linked up and waiting for you to write code in

Comment: @CaiusJard it worked, and u need to call the method on form_load()

Comment: What method are you talking about?

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm talking about this method, `PasswordTextbox_TextChanged` (the answer) and calling it in the `Form_Load`